# .net converting bytearray to double[]

Tags: .net

I am working with a database from a legacy app which stores 24 floating point values (doubles) as a byte array of length 192, so 8 bytes per value. This byte array is stored in a column of type `image` in a SQL Server 2005 database.

In my .net app I need to read this byte array and convert it to a array of type `Double[24]`. I can access the field easy enough `reader.GetBytes(...)` but how to convert the returned `ByteArray` to `Double[24]`

Any ideas?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, how is each set of 8 bytes represented? You *may* be able to use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx):

```
double[] doubles = new double[bytes.Length / 8];
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, doubles, 0, bytes.Length);
```

or you may need to use [`BitConverter.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble.aspx) repeatedly - or some custom conversion method.

Comment: Thanks, each 8 bytes is a standard IEEE 754-1985 double.

Comment: @AJ: In what endianness? I *believe* doubles have endianness internally, which makes comparisons really straightforward.

Comment: I'm not sure, an example of the first 8 bytes (in hex) is: 0000000000002840

Comment: It appears the documentation for BitConverter.ToDouble shows that BitConverter assumes the Byte array is little endian, whereas the hex string you've got is big endian.

Answer (score 0):

brute force:

```
double[] doubles = new double[24];   

for (int i=0; i < 24; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        doubles[i] += bytes[i*8 + j] << j*8;
    }
}
```

if the endianness is wrong, change the last term from j*8 to (7-j)*8;